# Titanfall periodic stuttering?

Tags: technical-issues, titanfall, framerate

I just downloaded Titanfall because it was free to play for 48 hours and on my i5-4670, GTX 770 Phantom 2GB, 8GB RAM system I get 60 fps maxed out except every ten seconds the game freezes for half a second then keeps going. If I watch my fraps counter it says 60, then drops to 34 and zooms back to 60 again when it freezes. I played the Beta earlier in the year on my old system (Core 2 Quad Q9505, GTX 470, 4GB RAM) which didn't play as well but didn't stutter.

On my current system I play with Vsync on but I use D3D Overrider to force triple buffering so that dropping to 55 fps with vsync doesn't drag me to down to 30.

The freezing isn't game breaking but it's pretty annoying. Anyone know how to fix this?

Update : It's nothing to do with my Vsync settings, I tried various combinations of Vsync options between the game and Nvidia Control Panel and D3D Overrider.

It also stutters the same on the main menu.

Comment: What else is running in the background?  Are you on latest NVidia drivers?  I have a similar setup with a 780 and don't see any stuttering.

Comment: I closed all background applications, I tried various drivers (including the latest beta drivers) and it's not a performance issue because it stutters even during the splash screen intro movie thing. Also I can't test anything now because the Game Time ran out and I haven't bought it.

Comment: I'm sorry you couldn't get any good testing in.  I'll give you my opinion that it's not a $60 game.  I ended up paying about $25 for it with some promo codes during a half-off weekend.  Unless you can get it for that cheap, I'd hold off.